# How to access angular router variable

Tags: angular

I am using the latest version of Angular, I believe it is NG4.

I have a route as follows:

```
{ path: 'banner/:set', component: AffiliateBannerComponent },
```

Which translates into a url:

```
https://www.example.com/banner/set1
https://www.example.com/banner/set2
https://www.example.com/banner/set3
```

When linking to each banner set I simply have my nav setup as:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/affiliate/banner', 'set1']">Banner Set 1</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['/affiliate/banner', 'set2']">Banner Set 2</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['/affiliate/banner', 'set3']">Banner Set 3</a></li>
```

From the code I want to grab the "set1" variable from the route.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject **`ActivatedRoute`** in your component, you'll be able to extract the route parameters

```
variableName:string;
ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe( params =>
        this.variableName = params['set'];
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for the initial page load. However, if the variable changes, how do I detect the change?

Comment: what do you mean by variable change? whenever there is a change in ur, it will detect

Comment: Ok I have udated my question a bit to include more detail. Your method works when I click on the route: set1, however when I click on set2 or set3 it is not detecting the change. I am guessting I need a click event of some kind rather than just a route?

Comment: It should detect . One suggestion I can give is try moving the code to constructor instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: The line should be `this.variableName = params['set'];` because the variable name is `:set`.